# Python: How to keep while loop running without repeatedly asking for raw_input()?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have the following While loop that will ask user input and then ask for it again and again before printing 'hello'. What I'd like to do is to ask the user for `raw_input` once and then run the while loop without the user having to type anything at all and keep the while loop running untill the user types `'q'`.

```
inp = raw_input()

while inp != 'q':
    inp = raw_input()
    print 'hello world'
```

Comment: This is trickier than you might expect since by default, input is blocking in Python.